# Google PHP API create users aliases

Tags: php, api

Based on example from https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/php (use https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

I can lists users aliases in Google Apps like in example:

```
[.....]
$results = $service->users->listUsers($optParams);
if (count($results->getUsers()) == 0) {
  print "No users found.\n";
} else {
  print "Users:\n";
  foreach ($results->getUsers() as $user) {
    $email =  $user->getPrimaryEmail();
   $fullname = $user->getName()->getFullName();
    $aliases = $user->getAliases();
[....]
```

I need to create more than one e-mail alias for the specified users.
Any idea where I find solution or specification how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

This would add a single alias to an existing user.

```
   // This is the user account we want to add the alias to
   $userKey = 'joesmo@my.test.domain.com';
   $alias   = 'myalias88@my.test.domain.com';

   $dir       = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
   $aliasObj  = new Google_Service_Directory_Alias( array( 'alias' =>  $alias ) );

   $results = $dir->users_aliases->insert($userKey, $aliasObj);
   print_r($results->alias);
```